# Laravel: Register and Login Do not Work on Online Server

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, postman

I have Laravel API project for authentication as Register and Login, It works fine on the local server but when I uploaded it to Online server it gives me this error when I try to Post using Postman:

```
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException: The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST. in file /home/magovfkb/star.magossa.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/AbstractRouteCollection.php on line 117
```

Any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Run `php artisan optimize:clear && php artisan config:cache && php artisan config:clear`
the above clears and rebuild the cache